# Make a copy of database with new collation

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a small hobby project in Django backed by Cloud SQL Postgres instance. Recently I realised that data sorting is not correct and identified it as issue with collation setting.

Indeed collation is set to `en_US.UTF8` instead of `pl_PL.utf8` (is there difference between `UTF8` and `utf8`?). [Using this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/275538/245667) I learned that it's not possible to just change the collation - you have to create database with new collation and then move the data.

I now created new database with:

```
create database db_pl WITH OWNER 'cloudsqlsuperuser' LC_COLLATE='pl_PL.utf8' LC_CTYPE='pl_PL.utf8' template template0;
```

I'm struggling with copying the data.

Will this `pg_dump` be fine and cause no collation change related issues?

```
pg_dump -h HOST -p PORT -U USER db -f db.sql
```

For restoring should `pg_restore` or `psql` be used? What options are needed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this pg_dump be fine and cause no collation change related
> issues?
> `pg_dump -h HOST -p PORT -U USER db -f db.sql`

Yes, that's fine. The resulting file is ready to be played into a database with a different default collation.

> *For restoring should pg_restore or psql be used? What options are
> needed?*

`psql` into an empty database that has been created with the desired `LC_COLLATE`.

`pg_restore` is only necessary when the dump file is in custom or directory format. Otherwise it's just a text file with SQL commands.